# Is there a way to make empty packages visible in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, filtering, package

Is there a way in Eclipse, to see empty parent packages? I have an issue freely viewing/accessing package `new.galaxywar.client.resources.images.game` that only contains 2 sub-packages:

[image: packages]

I tried creating that package again, because I thought that i might not have it in my eclipse project, but it won't let me:

[image: packages]

How do I prevent "views from filtering empty parent packages"?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In "Project Explorer" panel, click on the "View Menu" button (represented as a triangle).
Then go to "Customize View..." and deselect "Empty parent packages".

This should do the trick.

Comment: if your package is named the same as a daughter package, delect 'empty parent packages' as well.

Comment: You can get Project Explorer by Window > Show View > Project Explorer

Comment: Furthermore the package presentation needs to be flat instead of hierarchical.

Comment: "Customize View..." seems to be "Filters..." now and you have to select what should be excluded from the view 
so select "Empty parent packages" to hide the packages

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)

On the Project Explorer tab press the triangle in the upper right corner.

[image: image1]

In the menu choose **Filters and Customization...**

[image: image2]

In the Filters and Customization menu unmark **Empty packages** and **Empty parent packages**.

[image: image3]

Press **OK**

Now you should see the empty packages.

Answer (score 4):

While I'm not sure how to perfectly solve the problem, I do know that you can still access the package if you try creating a new file in there, for example package-info.java.

Try doing that by starting to add a Class as usual, but specify the package to be the package you can't seem to access in the Package Explorer.

Answer (score 4):

In *recent versions* of Eclipse, the steps in the accepted answer have slightly changed:

- In `Project Explorer` panel,click on `View Menu` button
- Then click on `Filter`
- Deselect `Empty Parent Packages`

*Eclipse IDE for Java Developers |
Version: Photon Release (4.8.0)
Build id: 20180619-1200*

Answer (score 0):

It's been 6 years since someone answered this question, and in the present day there is way more easiest methods to show hidden parent packages: "View menu" -> "Package presentation" -> "Hierarchical".

[View menu of project explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDiGm.png)

[Package presentation option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/memjf.png)

[Hierarchical option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVOwp.png)